# GTM + JS: How can I match IDs with Category names?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

On Google Tag Manager I need to create a custom JavaScript variable that gets an ID and then looks up for the correspondent category.

So I need ID = [15, 16, 17, 18}

to match these Categories = [A, B, C, D]

So basically, if ID = 15 the variable would return "A"

I've been able to write the code to get the IDs (and it's working). But I'm not sure what to do next, as I'm not very technical on JS

```
function () 
{
  var field = document.getElementById("AppointmentTypeID");
  return field.value || "";
}
```

Any thoughts?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use GTM native Lookup Table variable to set up mapping for ID. 
Just use an existing variable as input. Here's an example https://www.optimizesmart.com/understanding-lookup-table-variable-google-tag-manager/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const Categories = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
const IDS = [15, 16, 17, 19]
function getCat() 
{
  var field = document.getElementById("AppointmentTypeID"); // "15"
  return Categories[ IDS.indexOf(+field.value) ];
} 

const ID =  getCat();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It doesnt seem to be working though. I get this error message:  Error at line 2, character 6: Parse error. primary expression expected

Comment: @Dinomaster, can you show me your html code, or produce your code online in jsbin, fiddle ..etc